# MySQL insert error : ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '2525' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
var convID = 2525;
var contactUsername = 'blabla';
var userId = 100;
var contactId = 200;

var sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (FK_OWNERID, FK_USERID, FC_CONTACTNAME, `CONVERSATION_ID`)
                     VALUES (" + mysql.escape(userId) + "," + mysql.escape(contactId) + "," + mysql.escape(contactUsername) + "," + convID + "),
                     (" + mysql.escape(contactId) + "," + mysql.escape(userId) + "," + mysql.escape(username) + "," + convID + ")";
```

`Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '2525' in 'field list'
Fields are varchar(32) for both CONVERSATION_ID and FC_CONTACTNAME and ints for the 2 others.

What's wrong with this query? I even put the backticks around `CONVERSATION_ID` and it thinks the `convID` variable is a column...

Edit:

If my query is just that, then it works:

```
        var sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (`FK_OWNERID`, `FK_USERID`, `FC_CONTACTNAME`)
                 VALUES (" + mysql.escape(userId) + "," + mysql.escape(contactId) + "," + mysql.escape(contactUsername) + "),
                 (" + mysql.escape(contactId) + "," + mysql.escape(userId) + "," + mysql.escape(username) + ")";
```

Comment: What is the table structure (filed types, length, keys)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

make

```
" + convID + "
```

to

```
'" + convID + "'
```

Most likely its a string and the data type is varchar so u need to enclose within single quote.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem myself, I also didn't have all of my column names specified correctly. here is the code that finally worked.

```
var queryString = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (columnText, columnBool) VALUES ('" + val + "', FALSE);"
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a similar issue while trying to pass a parameter into a string in Node JS.

In the end, I was able to get a dynamic insertion into my MySQL database by using this line :

insertIntoNodeDirectory( '2', '"' + testMacAddress[0] + '"', '1');

This would enter the integer value 2, the string value contained in the testMacAddress array at index 0, and the integer value 1.

If i used this line: 
insertIntoNodeDirectory( '2', '" + testMacAddress[0] + "', '1');

without the additional single quotes around testMacAddress, the value inserted into the database was the string 'testMacAddress[0]'. Not what I wanted.

Comment: I highly doubt this is what OP wanted to fix, nevertheless what you just said is true, actually, if his 'convID' is already something like '2525' that might be his problem

Answer (score 1):

```
var _name = req.body.name
var _age = req.body.age
var _table = 'people'

const _query = "INSERT INTO " + _table + " (name, age) VALUES ('" + _name + "', '" + _age + "' );"
```

This  is work for me, main issue occur in query.